# When drawing map and players, output is blank canvas

Tags: javascript

I've been making a little game since a while, and i discovered a problem.

When i want to draw my map and the player

```
var Img = {};
    Img.player = new Image();
    Img.player.src = '/client/img/player.png';
    Img.map = new Image();
    Img.player.src = '/client/img/map.png';

    var Player = function(initPack){
        var self = {};
        self.id = initPack.id;
        self.number = initPack.number;
        self.x = initPack.x;
        self.y = initPack.y;

        self.draw = function(){
            var x = self.x - Player.list[selfId].x + WIDTH/2;
            var y = self.y - Player.list[selfId].y + HEIGHT/2;
            
            var width = Img.player.width*2;
            var height = Img.player.height*2;
            
            
            ctx.drawImage(Img.player,
                0,0,Img.player.width,Img.player.height, // right here
                x-width/2,y-height/2,width,height);

        Player.list[self.id] = self;
        return self;
    }
```

and then this:

```
setInterval(function(){
        if(selfId == null)
            return;
        ctx.clearRect(0,0,600,600);
        drawMap();
        for(var i in Player.list)
            Player.list[i].draw();
    },1000/30);

    var drawMap = function(){
        ctx.drawImage(Img.map,0,0);
    }
```

it just gives me a blank canvas.

Comment: is your `selfId` variable `null` all the time?

Comment: @JulekPL I have a little challenge for you that may help us and you to resolve the problem.
Write a simple proof-of-concept in code snippet. There we could focus on that critical path.
Please edit your question and ping me back.